# Image of power of linear operator.

Tags: linear-algebra

How can we show that if $f:V\to V$
Then for each $m\in \mathbb {N}$ $$\operatorname{im}(f^{m+1})\subset \operatorname{im}(f^m)$$
Please help,I am stuck on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $x\in\text{im}(f^{m+1})$. This means that $x=f^{m+1}(y)$ for some $y\in V$. Then
$$
x=f^{m+1}(y)=f^m(f(y))\in\text{im}(f^m).
$$

Comment: How can I show that at some point it is equality i.e the subspaces equal?

Comment: It is not true in general.

Comment: I have a condition that f is not nilpotent and linear operator

Comment: Still not true. Take the shift operator on a Hilbert space, for example.

Comment: V is finite dimensional K.vector space.

Comment: You never said so. In that case the answer is trivial, as you have a decreasing sequence of subspaces, and thus a decreasing sequence of dimensions. It necessarily has to stabilize.

Comment: can it become of dimension 0,i.e 0 itself?

Comment: Not if $f$ is not nilpotent, as you said.

Answer (score 0):

Try it first with $m=1$. A typical member of $\def\im{\operatorname{im}} \im(f^2)$ looks like $f(f(x))$, right? Now can you see why that is a member of $\im(f)$? Next, repeat with $m=2$. Do you see how that generalizes to higher $m$?

Answer (score 0):

For $m\in \mathbb{N}$ :
$$f^m(f(V))\subset imf^m$$ since $f(V)\subset V$, i.e $$imf^{m+1}\subset imf^m$$.